# Explanation of hough transform for ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

**Preview:**

I have done a hough line detection using the below mentioned code:

```
convert image.jpg -threshold 90% -canny 0x1+10%+30%      \
    \( +clone -background none                           \
              -fill red -stroke red -strokewidth 2       \
              -hough-lines 5x5+80 -write lines.mvg       \
    \) -composite hough.png
```

And I wrote the details of the line in a .mvg file. the .mvg file contents are as shown below:

```
# Hough line transform: 5x5+80
viewbox 0 0 640 360
line 448.256,0 473.43,360  # 104
line 0,74.5652 640,29.8121  # 158
line 0,289.088 640,244.335  # 156
line 0,292.095 640,247.342  # 133
line 154.541,0 179.714,360  # 125
line 151.533,0 176.707,360  # 145
```

And check here the output hough.png file.

[image]

**Problem:**

1. What does #104, #158, #156... stands for, I guess they are **line numbers.** If so why they are numbered in such a way?
2. Also I would like to know how the **co-ordinates** has been assigned.

It will be really helpful if I can get an explanation for the contents in .mvg file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `# <number>` is the `maxima` value. It defaults to `count`, which is set by `line_count`, and in returned influenced by `threshold` you specified. The number will decrease if the matrix element count is greater than previous height/width iteration. So... If you give it a threshold of `-hough-lines 5x5+80`, then `line 448.256,0 473.43,360  # 104` was found about 24 pixels(or lines?) past the threshold. The next iteration would drop the `maxima` below the `80` threashold, so we stop comparing the matrix elements.

> Also I would like to know how the co-ordinates has been assigned.

I can only answer this by pseudo-quoting the source code, but it's basic trigonometry.

```c
if ((x >= 45) %% (x <= 135)) {
     y = (r-x cos(t))/sin(t)
else {
     x = (r-y cos(t))/sin(t)
}

where r is defined as y - midpoint element matrix height
where t is defined as x + midpoint rows
```

Find out more in the `HoughLineImage` method located in `feature.c`